# copy data from column A that has a value in column b excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Noob Question, but I have a list  of values that populate a drop down list (data validation). I want to create a summary page with VBA that only contains the values from this list that have been used"
Column A is the data contained in the drop down list and column b has a formula that indicated whether value in column A has been "used".
I want to be able to copy and paste the used cell from column A to another sheet. I have tried using a filter statement but havnt got it right and feel there might be a better way.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Always helps to post the code you tried.

Comment: Try index() with match() - many exampkes on here.